# OnLostPassword with ReactNative and Meteor

Tags: meteor, react-native, meteor-accounts

I have a ReactNative app with Meteor as a backend. 
Here is the code to reset the password. The documentation says it sends an email. The email does appear in the Meteor console, but it says " (Mail not sent; to enable sending, set the MAIL_URL environment variable.). 
The Meteor doc says to install "meteor email" which I did, but no success.

```js
onLostPassword = (emails) => {
  const {email}= this.state;
  Accounts.forgotPassword({email}, function (err){
    if (err){
      console.log(err.reason);
    }else{
      console.log('works');
      Meteor.call('onSendResetPasswordEmail');
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: The doc not only says to install meteor mail but also to properly confugure your mail server. Do you have your mailserver configured and also set the environment variable as schown in the docs?

Comment: You're right, but  have no idea how to "set the MAIL_url environment variable" in ReactNative, sorry very newbie to this!